# Solid partial horizontal line in Markdown

Tags: html, markdown

How can I create a partial colored line in Markdown? I am using

```html
 <hr style="border:0.3px solid green; width:40%"> </hr>
```

But I am getting gray full line. What is my mistake? I am rendering it in JupyterLab

Comment: Where and how are you rendering this? In some platforms this will get stripped out, e.g. in GitHub READMEs.

Comment: added. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put a semicolon between green and width, to separate the two values. Otherwise, it shows up as an invalid property value, and the hr is just a regular horizontal line.
You could fix it with

```html
<hr style="border: 0.3px solid green; width:40%;"></hr>
```

Comment: Thank you very much; this addressed my question.